# Is a magnetic field required for electromagnetic energy flow through an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism

My (perhaps flawed) understanding:

- Existence of voltage results in an electric field.
- Existence of current results in a magnetic field.
- Electromagnetic energy flows in waves in the electric field.

The power law says that current is required for energy flow. Is this because a magnetic field is required for energy to flow through the electric field?

If so, how does the magnetic field cause energy flow?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a little too loosey-goosey as is, but it has the germ of a correct idea in it.

> Electromagnetic energy flows in waves in the electric field.

In a DC circuit, there are no electromagnetic waves. Actually, energy can be considered to flow any time there is a nonzero [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) (WP). I think the image you really want is the following (from the WP article):

[image: poynting vector in a DC circuit]

Red is the electric field, green is the magnetic field, and blue is the Poynting vector.

Comment: You could question the use of the Poynting vector I  such a static case, as is done on the textbook of Panofsky and Phillips.

Comment: @my2cts: What's their criticism?

Comment: It looks like to have a nonzero Poynting vector, there must a magnetic field and an electric field, so that answers that part. Thank you. Does the second part of my question make sense? ("How does the magnetic field cause energy flow?") Or am I still asking non-sensical things?

Comment: @Ben Crowell From memory it is that for a static E and  static B the Poynting vector predicts an energy flow, which is counterintuitive. I will look up the exact statement asap.

Comment: @lyndon: *How does the magnetic field cause energy flow?* I would put it a different way, that the magnetic field is part of how we compute an energy flow.

Answer (score 0):

@Ben Crowell In my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078 I show that the Poynting vector should be replaced by $ \epsilon_0 \dot { \vec A} \times \vec A$, which predicts the energy transport to be zero for static cases. In many cases the two give the same result.

Comment: If it predicts energy transfer to be zero in the static case then it is clearly falsified.